# Solutions for "What is Mathematics?" by Richard Courant

Tags: self-learning, advice, learning

I am currently reading through Courant's "What is Mathematics?" Most of the time I am not taking the exercises too seriously, given that I am reading this for pleasure, and that often my solutions are easy to verify. Nonetheless there are frequent cases where I'm not sure I've done the exercise correctly and I'm genuinely interested in the solution. Since the book has been around for so long, I assumed I would be able to find a collection of solutions or a study guide, but I can't find any.

Does anyone know where I could find solutions for the exercises in this book?

Thanks!

Comment: DaedalusBloom is as literary a name as ever borne by anyone who raised a mathematical question. I love that great book.

Comment: it is a higher pleasure to understand the exercises enough, too seriously, to see better